# react testing library - userevent.keyboard v14

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

while I use:

```
await event.type(nameField, data.name);
```

my field is updated with the text and tests pass

but while using:

```
  await event.click(nameField);
  await event.keyboard(data.name);
```

the text field is not updated with the text and then tests fail

What can be the reason for that?

- it happens in @testing-library/user-event@v14,
  but still works in @testing-library/user-event@13.5

Comment: Which version are you using specifically?  It appears to work in the latest version: Take a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-rebbtf?file=index.mjs